# Query for displaying UNIX files created on particular timestamp

Tags: find, timestamps

I wish to list down all files which were created on particular time.

(For ex: files created on time: Nov 13 09:09)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio     43268 Nov 13 09:02 sendEsbUpdateEvents.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio    333420 Nov 13 09:09 jobwatch_bittest1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio   6113535 Nov 13 09:09 CDRExtract.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio     10268 Nov 13 09:09 cdrextract_111309095100_26224.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio 322398684 Nov 13 09:10 export_docs_log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitt1 cerillio   2911940 Nov 13 09:14 sendBillNotifications.log
```

So let me know single liner query if any.

Comment: Have a look at this [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/580273/ubuntu-linux-find-files-between-specific-times) answer.

Comment: That time is the last modification time, not the creation time (unless you used `ls -lU` (inode birth time) on FreeBSD or derivatives)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU or FreeBSD `find`:

```
find . -newermt '2014-11-13 9:09' ! -newermt '2014-11-13 9:10'
```

Note that it will report a file last modified at 9:10:00.000000000 and not one at 9:09:00.000000000 but should otherwise be OK for the other 60,000,000,000 nanoseconds in between.

With GNU `find`, assuming file and directory names don't contain newline characters, you could also do:

```
find . -printf '%T+/%p\n' | grep -Po '^2014-11-13\+09:09.*?/\K.*'
```

(or if they may contain newline characters:

```
find . -printf '%T+/%p\0' | grep -Pzo '^2014-11-13\+09:09.*?/\K.*' | tr \\0 \\n
```